# Spring Data JPA - Query with no arguments

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to make a query that compare 2 columns **inside** my table and therefore there is no need to add arguments to the query. For example: I have a table Product and I want to find all the products that has a stock <= stock_min

```
+----+-----------+-------+-----------+
| ID |   NAME    | STOCK | STOCK_MIN |
+----+-----------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | product 1 |     2 |         3 |
|  2 | product 2 |     3 |         1 |
|  3 | product 3 |     4 |         5 |
+----+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

How can I do that with Spring Data JPA?

Declaring something like this in my ProductRepository throws an error

```
List<Product> findByStockIsLessThanEqualStockMin();
```

this also doesn't work

```
@Query("select p from product p where p.stock <= p.stockmin")
List<Product> findByStockIsLessThanEqualStockMin();
```

All the examples in the [Spring Data JPA documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) use some arguments in the query, but I don't want to do that because the stockMin attribute is different for every row in my Product table.

**[FIXED]**
The problem was super dumb. I forget to capitalize my entity and the `select` was not necessary. Below query works fine:

```
@Query("from Product p where p.stock <= p.stockMin")
List<Product> findByStockIsLessThanEqualStockMin();
```

pd: that was my first question here. Thank you all guys! :)

Comment: Not sure if I can help, so did you try findAllBy... ?

Comment: can you try like this : findByStockLessThanEqual(stockmin); Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Use a native Query http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries

Comment: Please post the Producto class. The query depends on the structure of this entity.

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned code is working fine. There might be issue with the in your entity class.

```
package com.demo.account.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Integer stock;

    private Integer stockMin;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Integer stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public Integer getStockMin() {
        return stockMin;
    }

    public void setStockMin(Integer stockMin) {
        this.stockMin = stockMin;
    }

    public Product() {

    }

    public Product(String name, Integer stock, Integer stockMin) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.stockMin = stockMin;
    }

}


package com.demo.account.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.demo.account.model.Product;

@Repository
public interface ProductDao extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {

    @Query("from Product p where p.stock <= p.stockMin")
    List<Product> findByStockIsLessThanEqualStockMin();

}

Product product = new Product("Mobile",10,3);
            productDao.save(product);

            product = new Product("Curtains",15,15);
            productDao.save(product);

            product = new Product("Clothing",5,15);
            productDao.save(product);

            System.out.println(productDao.findByStockIsLessThanEqualStockMin());
```

Comment: The entity class is ok, but your answer give the the inside!. My problem is that I have use `product` instead of `Product` in my @Query. Thank you!